# Nested lightning:button onClick Not Firing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, onclick, lightning-card

When I have a button inside a component inside a `lightning:card` either as a body element or an action, the `onClick` is never fired. If I move the `lightning:button` outside of the container, the event fires as expected. I've tried searching everywhere for how to handle this situation as I'm sure it's a scoping issue, but I can't find a solid answer.

Here's an example component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <lightning:card title="Program Enrollment" iconName="standard:marketing_actions">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="Request" onclick="{!v.requestHelp}" />
        </aura:set>
        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height: 5rem;">
            Nothing here to see!
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    requestHelp : function() {
        alert("hello");
    }
})
```

Comment: it will be onclick={!c.requestHelp} not 'v.requestHelp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be  `c.requestHelp` not `v.requestHelp`

`c.` is used to call controller functions and `v.` is used to access attribute values

Comment: doh! thank you!